# Cannot install "mediapipe" library

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

I am trying `pip3 install mediapipe` but I am getting an error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

My Python version is 3.7.9 and pip version is 20.3.1.

Comment: What is your operating system? Do you have 32 bit python by any chance?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am using macOS and 64 bit python

Comment: It looks like there's already an issue raised on this over [github](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1405). The issue is open and unresolved as of now.

Comment: I had the same problem. my python was 3.8 32bit. I tried python 3.9 and It didn't work either. but with python 3.7.9 64bit and pip 20.1.1, it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by typing `py -m pip install mediapipe` instead.

Comment: Why does this work? Since when can you just type `py` for `python`?

Comment: `py` is the python launcher. It is normally bundled with python for windows and it is used to manage multiple python versions. The `py` command defaults to the newest version of python installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to install MediaPipe via pip using macOs 10.13 with Python 3.7.10. I ended up looking at the "Download Files" in Mediapipe's PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files) and found out that all wheel files for macOs referred to macOs 10.15 (Catalina), so I upgraded and now the installation is correctly done.

I don't know why there's a need for that specific macOs version, nor how to change it to work on other versions, so my advice would be to just upgrade to macOs 10.15 if you are running on earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled Python version 3.7.7

Answer (score 1):

I used conda to make a virtual environment with an earlier version of Python that is supported:

```
conda create --name mp_env numpy mp python=3.7.2
```

And then:

```
conda activate mp_env
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 64-bit version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with:

- Python 3.10.5
- pip 22.2.2
- mediapipe==0.8.10.1