# Having trouble installing mediapipe

Tags: python, mediapipe

I have:
macOS Mojave version 10.14.6
python      3.8.3
pip          21.1.3

pip install mediapipe
py -m pip install mediapipe
…
all give the following two errors:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

Also what does version refer to? pip, python , mediapipe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install "mediapipe" library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172162/cannot-install-mediapipe-library)

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, then just use `conda install mediapipe` in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Note: To make Mediapipe work with TensorFlow, please set Python 3.7 as the default Python version and install the Python “six” library by running pip3 install --user six.

https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant but I was running into this issue on an M1 MacBook Pro and the issue seems to be that mediapipe doesn't have an Apple silicon version. Note all the releases for mediapipe are x86/x64:
https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files

I found a fix here, someone compiled it for silicon: https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3277

Basically,

```
pip install mediapipe-silicon
```