# can't install mediapipe? python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I have tried to use `pip install mediapipe`, and other similar methods of pip install to install mediapipe as i need it for one of my projects. I am stumped and don't know what to do anymore. I have python 3.8 and the latest version of pip.
This is the error I keep getting:
[image]

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install "mediapipe" library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172162/cannot-install-mediapipe-library)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the specific version of the lib

such as:

pip install mediapipe==0.8.9.1 (the version which you want.)

Comment: I get the same error:
```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.8.9.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.8.9.1``` @baozilaji

Comment: maybe you could try some other version of mediapipe or maybe you could change the pypi repository refer to https://mirrors.sustech.edu.cn/help/pypi.html#_2-configure-index-url

Answer (score 0):

*You have to change the python version to **3.7 with 64bit** then only you can install it
if you can create a virtual environment for it as well so that will do great*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to fix the problem.
The issue is that the newest Python version will not be able to download mediapipe via using pip.

Download and install Python version 3.10.10
(make sure you install it to different file, use custom installation so you will not overwrite your newest python)

once you do that, lets say when you use PyCharm just create the new project only this time use older python version: Python 3.10.10

Now command pip install mediapipe will work.

If for your project you will have another errors and you will need newer pip version, at this point is allright to update for newer pip since your mediapipe is already downloaded. So when neccesery you will type:
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip